# Error with node-gyp during npm install on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm getting the following error with node-gyp when I do npm install on Windows 10 using GitBash. I've tried reinstalling node-gyp again but doesn't help. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
$ npm install
npm WARN package.json lms@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json lms@1.0.0 No README data

> libxmljs@0.14.3 install C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Projects\brainiac\node_modules\js2xml\node_modules\libxmljs
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Projects\brainiac\node_modules\js2xml\node_modules\libxmljs>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Projects\brainiac\node_modules\js2xml\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Projects\brainiac\node_modules\js2xml\node_modules\libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! libxmljs@0.14.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.14.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs libxmljs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Projects\brainiac\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I think it's related to not being able to find your visual studio `cl.exe` to compile. I have to *strongly* suggest using the `windows-build-tools`, if you aren't. Installation instructions found on node-gyp's [readme](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp). This will automatically install all tools required to build native modules on windows.

Comment: You may also need to update your `npm`, as seen [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/802#issuecomment-232865395) (I had to on my windows 10 machine, at any rate).

Comment: I've tried installed the latest npm version and windows-build-tools but still didn't fix the error

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Visual Studio 2015/other full package and get such error it might help to run npm installation from "VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt"
or call first "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"